# Total of sum when group by name then do total of Amount

Tags: sql

```
select CandidateName, SUM(Amount) as Amount
from MaseHisab
where Member = 'ABC+DEF+GHI'
group by CandidateName




CandidateName   Amount
jain            72.00
rakesh          30.00
shams           110.00
```

Comment: Sample data can help us understand this more! Also which database?

Comment: Which DBMS? MySQL? Or SQL Server? Or Postgres? ... And the results you show are the results you are getting with your query or the results you want to get? How are are the results you are getting different from the results you want to get? Do you only want to add a sum line with the total amount of 212?

Comment: add the dbms type you are using!!! then supply sample data and the expected result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `SQL-Server` then
use `with rollup`.that will give you sum of amount column at the end of that

```
select isnull(CandidateName,'Total'),SUM(Amount) as Amount
from MaseHisab
where Member='ABC+DEF+GHI' group by CandidateName
with rollup
```

o/p

```
CandidateName   Amount
jain            72.00
rakesh          30.00
shams           110.00
NULL            212.00
```

**EDIT**

use `isnull` for that. see the above query

```
isnull(CandidateName,'Total')
```

If you are using other databases

```
COALESCE(CandidateName,'Total')
```

Comment: i want in place of NULL write Total

Comment: @Shams: You still haven't told us your DBMS. In SQL-Server there is `GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP` and `ISNULL`, whereas in other DBMS it's standard `GROUP BY ROLLUP(...)` and `COALESCE`.